# List of integer doesn't add a value from database

Tags: .net, vb.net, list

```
Dim id As Integer
Dim tempIdList As List(Of Integer)
```

---

```
If dr.Read() Then
      Do
         Dim loc As String
         loc = dr("CurrentLocation").ToString()
         id = dr("ID")
         'tempIdList.Add(dr("ID"))
         'tempIdList.Add(id)
             If loc = comboFrom.Text Then
                  isContinue = True
             End If
      Loop While dr.Read
End If
```

I have tried those commented code. But I get `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.
I tried adding a break point, and it seemed that the list does not get a value, just `Nothing` whilst `id` has the value of the ID from the access database.

What is wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tempIdList` is probably `Nothing`. You have to create an instance first with the `New` keyword:

```
Dim tempIdList As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)
```